# UIWebView not displaying .doc files with correct font size in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I'm trying to display the local .doc files in UIWebView from main bundle.

I added the following code to display in UIWebView.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"LocalDocument" withExtension:@"doc"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[self.webView loadRequest:theRequest];
```

UIWebview displays the document correctly, But the problem is it doesn't display the text "`Header`" in correct font size in iPhone.

**iPhone screenshot**
[image: iPhone screenshot]

**iPad screenshot**
[image: iPad screenshot]

In the word document I added the text "`Header`" with font `size 22` and description text with font `size 14`.

In iPad it displays `correctly`, but in iPhone it display both text in font `size 14`.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
NSString*fileName= @"LocalDocument";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"doc"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO]];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

And use custom font for UIWebview

```
NSString *myText=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html><body><script>var str = '%@'; document.write(str.fontsize(%d).fontcolor('green'));</script></body></html>",myString,textFontSize];
```